# Byte complie predictive mode

Tags: byte-compilation, predictive-mode

I'm trying to byte compile predictive mode and I have an issue that I can't solve. If I clone it from the [official repo](http://www.dr-qubit.org/git/predictive.git), and `make` it, I get:

```
In toplevel form:
predictive-auto-overlay-auto-dict.el:35:1:Error: Symbol’s function definition is void: trie-lexical-binding-p
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'predictive-auto-overlay-auto-dict.elc' failed
make: *** [predictive-auto-overlay-auto-dict.elc] Error 1
```

If I download the [tar ball](http://www.dr-qubit.org/download.php?file=predictive/predictive.tar.gz) I face this error:

```
makeinfo predictive-user-manual.texinfo -o predictive-user-manual.info
make: makeinfo: Command not found
Makefile:154: recipe for target 'predictive-user-manual.info' failed
make: *** [predictive-user-manual.info] Error 127
```

In both cases it compiles some stuff and eventually fails. I'm quite new to *not* using package manger, so *I* might be doing something wrong here though.

Comment: This seems like missing dependencies. The second will be easier to correct (probably). Depending on your distro, search for the package which provides `makeinfo` program and install that. In Ubuntu, for example, `texi2html` seems to provide this program. As for the first one: it assumes that you have installed some ELisp package (in Emacs) that defines variable `trie-lexical-binding-p` - maybe you have it, but it's a wrong version, or maybe you don't have it it at all... you'd need to look into sources to know for sure.

Comment: The `trie` package comes with `predictive`. Your first question sounds like a bug. Report it to the author.

Comment: @wvxvw, thank you for the reply. It's a fresh installation of emacs. I have only installed `auctex` and that's it. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @wvxvw, installing `Texi2HTML` unfortunately didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, [suggestion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41709/byte-complie-predictive-mode/41727#comment65542_41709) by @wvxvw regarding installing `texi2html` didn't solve the issue. However, after installing `texinfo`, distribution from tarball compiled. Git distribution still not working.